# Merge two tables from two excel files and create a column with the name of the corresponding excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, merge, fusion

I would like to merge 2 tables from two different Excel files.
I'd like to add a column in the new table to indicate the name of the excel file in question.

The aim would be to merge a multitude of tables with a column indicating the name of the file.

file_path = "C:\excel files"
myfile = os.listdir(file_path)
for f in myfile:
with open(f) as infile:
contents = infile.read()
print(contents)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pandas`, can you try the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path

fpath1 = Path('file1/path/filename2.xlsx')
fpath2 = Path('file1/path/filename2.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(fpath1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(fpath2)
rename_cols = {col: f'{col}_{fpath2.stem}' for col in df2.columns}
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns=rename_cols)], ignore_index=True)
```